# Is there a scaling Factor method For Multi Resolution support of Android

Tags: java, android

Currently in order to do multi-resolution you have to provide all the images inside the res directory, which makes the app quite large in size, especially if the app has a lot of images or supports tablets[xxxhdpi] images.

So basically i want to know how to make a scaling factor algorithm like that in cocos2dx, in which you provide the device width and height with image width and height to give a scaling factor for the image for all the devices. so can store image in one res folder and then scale that image according to my requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I reckon that this what u are looking for:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;//gets screen height
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;//gets screen width
image.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (width/4);
image.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height/4);
```

Comment: thanks for the swift reply, but this only gives the four values which i mentioned already were possible to get a know how to get them, i wanted to know how to use these values to  determine a scaling factor so that i can scale the image accordingly...

Comment: image.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (width/4);

image.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height/4);

These lines to scale? Also ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_image); before these lines.